# how do I validate my textbox to only display more than or equal to 0?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have one button to increment the value of the text box by 1 and another button to do the opposite. I want to know how to validate it so the number doesn't go below zero.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, i) Then
        i += 1
    Else
        i = 0
    End If
    TextBox2.Text = i.ToString()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, i) Then
        i -= 1
    Else
        i = 0
    End If
    TextBox2.Text = i.ToString()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two easy options:

- before you decrement the number, check if it is greater than zero
- after you decrement the number, check if is less than zero and if so, set it to zero.

So..

```
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, i) AndAlso (i > 0) Then
        i -= 1
    Else
```

or...

```
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, i) Then
        i -= 1
        If i < 0 Then
            i = 0
        End If
    Else
```

You could also use

```
i = Math.Max(0, i - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Which option is more professional? or are they all as good as each other.

Comment: @CathaysMafia If there is a possibility of something else changing the text in `TextBox2`, say to "-99", then the second and third code samples would correct `i` back to zero but the first would not. The second sample gives you the possibility of alerting the user if they try to go below zero. There is no "most professional" way of doing it without knowing the overall context.